# ProtractorJS Specs Not Run, Browser get data; only

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I run my protractorjs `conf.js`, but the browser address only show `data;` and never run my spec file.

Folder Structure & conf.js
[image: Folder Structure & conf.js]

spec.js
[image: spec.js]

Start webdriver-manager
[image: Start webdriver-manager]

Run protractor
[image: Run Protractor]

Browser
[image: Browser]

Error result when closed the browser
[image: Error Result When Closed The Browser]

Here complete for error messages:

```
johanessurya@BlackHat:/mnt/drive_e/vagrant/bsi (r-50)$ protractor protractorjs/conf.js
[14:44:47] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[14:44:47] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[14:45:17] E/launcher - unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609551 (5d576e9a44fe4c5b6a07e568f1ebc753f1214634),platform=Linux 4.15.0-33-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 29.49 seconds
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'BlackHat', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-33-generic', java.version: '10.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
[14:45:17] E/launcher - WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609551 (5d576e9a44fe4c5b6a07e568f1ebc753f1214634),platform=Linux 4.15.0-33-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 29.49 seconds
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'BlackHat', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-33-generic', java.version: '10.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/home/johanessurya/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/home/johanessurya/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (/home/johanessurya/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/home/johanessurya/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (/home/johanessurya/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
    at createDriver (/home/johanessurya/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:170:33)
    at Builder.build (/home/johanessurya/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:626:16)
    at Hosted.getNewDriver (/home/johanessurya/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:53:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/home/johanessurya/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
    at q.then.then (/home/johanessurya/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29)
    at _fulfilled (/home/johanessurya/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/johanessurya/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/johanessurya/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
[14:45:17] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

---

I tried to run my old protractor tester that run correctly before. When I try to run it, the result is the same. **Maybe I install or setup the wrong version**

System Spec:

- Ubuntu
- NPM: 3.5.2
- Node: 8.10.0
- Protractor: 5.4.1
- jasmine v3.3.0
- jasmine-core v3.3.0
- webdriver-manager: 12.1.0

---

**UPDATE:** I tried using firefox as browserName and it works, but not chrome. It seems to be a problem with chromedriver. Here is my `webdriver-manager` `config.json`

```
{
  "webdriverVersions": {
    "selenium": "2.53.1",
    "chromedriver": "2.27",
    "geckodriver": "v0.13.0",
    "iedriver": "2.53.1",
    "androidsdk": "24.4.1",
    "appium": "1.6.5"
  },
  "cdnUrls": {
    "selenium": "https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/",
    "chromedriver": "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/",
    "geckodriver": "https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/",
    "iedriver": "https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/",
    "androidsdk": "http://dl.google.com/android/"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solve the problem. It's because incompatible `chromedriver` with my OS(Ubuntu 18.04).

I just google that someone successfully using `chromedriver=2.41`. So, I just downgrade it: `webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 2.41`

Reference: https://tecadmin.net/setup-selenium-chromedriver-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 2):

Did you updated your drivers?
webdriver-manager update

in case you need to pass the proxy use this command

```
 webdriver-manager update --proxy=myProxyServer:Port
```

Try to change the conf file to the example bellow

```
// An example configuration file
exports.config = {
// The address of a running selenium server.
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

// Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
capabilities: {
  browserName: 'chrome',
  chromeOptions: {
    args: [
          '--start-maximized' //in case of non headless execution
          ]
},

// Spec patterns are relative to the configuration file location passed
// to protractor (in this example conf.js).
// They may include glob patterns.
specs: ['example-spec.js'],

// Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
jasmineNodeOpts: {
  showColors: true, // Use colors in the command line report.
}
};
```

Comment: Yes, I did. I just update my question. I add my webdriver-manager config.json.

Comment: ok, download the latest version of Chrome-driver then, the latest is 2.44 (https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.44/)

webdriver-manager update --chromedriver

Comment: I just tried it and it said **I/update - chromedriver: chromedriver_2.44 up to date**

Comment: In your config.json, still the old version? this is my config.json as example:
{
 "chrome": {
  "last": "C:\\the whole path\\selenium\\chromedriver_2.44.exe",
  "all": ["C:\\the whole path\\selenium\\chromedriver_2.43.exe",
  "C:\\the whole path\\selenium\\chromedriver_2.44.exe"]
 }
}

Comment: After I downgrade, I saw it would run correctly when I set `directconnect:true`. No, my version is the newest one **2.44**. I downgrade to **2.41**, it run correctly with `directconnect:true`